# how to change legend, country labels and size of my multiple area plots with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, legend, patchwork

I have trying to change my legends and the names of the countries that appear multiple times in one of the areas plots. [image]

i. As you can see the legend appears several times. I want this legend to be place like in the last picture. for both: symptoms and comorbidities:

1. if this can appear above the whole plot as: Symptoms: chest pains, chills, etc. and Comorbidities: asthma, diabetes type one, etc.

ii. the sizes of each area plots are different

2. They should be equal in size.

iii. Also the country labels. Nicely, these are appearing once. Would want them to appear like the last picture:

A - India,
B - Pakistan,
C - United Kingdom and positioned on the left hand side above each set of area plots.

Here is an example of the way I want my plot to look like[image]

Here is the code and the fake datasets:

```
sympt_count_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(count_symptoms, ggplot2::aes(x = age_band, y = Count, group = symptoms, fill = symptoms)) +
  ggplot2::geom_area( color = "white") + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) + 
  ggplot2::facet_grid(Country ~.)

sympt_count_plot


sympt_percent_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(count_symptoms, ggplot2::aes(x = age_band, y = Percent, group = symptoms, fill = symptoms)) +
  ggplot2::geom_area( color = "white") + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) + 
  ggplot2::facet_grid(Country ~.)

sympt_percent_plot


library(patchwork)
plot_sympt <- sympt_count_plot + sympt_percent_plot

plot_sympt



comorb_count_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(count_comorbidities, ggplot2::aes(x = age_band, y = Count, group = comorbidities, fill = comorbidities)) +
  ggplot2::geom_area( color = "white") + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  #viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) + 
  ggplot2::facet_grid(Country ~.)

comorb_count_plot




comorb_percent_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(count_comorbidities, ggplot2::aes(x = age_band, y = Percent, group = comorbidities, fill = comorbidities)) +
  ggplot2::geom_area( color = "white") + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  #viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) + 
  ggplot2::facet_grid(Country ~.)

comorb_percent_plot


plot_comorb <- comorb_count_plot + comorb_percent_plot

plot_comorb

plot_sympt + plot_comorb
```

Is there a way I can get them the way I want. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can harvest the legends using `cowplot::get_legend` then arrange them however you like. Here's a full reprex:

# Load packages and data

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

git <- "https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/raw/master"
count_symptoms <- readr::read_csv(paste0(git, "/fake_symptoms.csv"))
count_comorbidities <- readr::read_csv(paste0(git, "/fake_comorbidities.csv"))
```

# plot 1

```
sympt_count_plot <- ggplot(count_symptoms) +
  geom_area(aes(x = age_band, y = Count, group = symptoms, fill = symptoms),
            color = "white") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), 
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +  
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Country, ncol = 1)
```

# plot 2

```
sympt_percent_plot <- ggplot(count_symptoms) +
  geom_area(aes(x = age_band, y = Percent, group = symptoms, fill = symptoms),
            color = "white") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", color = "white")) + 
  facet_wrap(~Country, ncol = 1)
```

# plot 3

```
comorb_count_plot <- ggplot(count_comorbidities) +
  geom_area(aes(age_band, Count, group = comorbidities, fill = comorbidities),
            color = "white") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"),
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Oranges") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", color = "white")) + 
  facet_wrap(~Country, ncol = 1)
```

# plot 4

```
comorb_percent_plot <- ggplot(count_comorbidities) +
  geom_area(aes(age_band, Percent, group = comorbidities, fill = comorbidities),
            color = "white") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c( "0-19" ,"20-39", "40-59","60+"), 
                   expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Oranges") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", color = "white")) + 
  facet_wrap(~Country, ncol = 1)
```

# Stitch plots together

```
plot_sympt <-  sympt_count_plot + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
               sympt_percent_plot + theme(legend.position = "none")

plot_comorb <- comorb_count_plot + theme(legend.position = "none") +
               comorb_percent_plot + theme(legend.position = "none")

plot_legend <- wrap_plots(
  cowplot::get_legend(sympt_percent_plot),
  cowplot::get_legend(comorb_percent_plot),
  ncol = 1)
  
wrap_plots(plot_sympt, plot_comorb, plot_legend,
                     nrow = 1, widths = c(2, 2, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you Allan!is there a way to control the country labels?

Comment: @GaB yes. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: If you see the in the actual post, the second picture has continents at the top of each set of area plots. I want the same with countries. Also the legend, want it on the top of the plot. In four lines.

Comment: @GaB quite a bit of effort - but see my update for a full reprex